# How to receive incoming SMS only from selected phone number?

Tags: android

I have a problem. I can read the SMS and automatically display it in EditText. But how to read SMS only from a selected phone number?

```
package com.example.probe;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class OTPReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static EditText editText_otp;

    public void setEditText_otp(EditText editText) {
        OTPReceiver.editText_otp = editText;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
        for (SmsMessage smsMessage : smsMessages) {
            String message_body = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            String getOTP = message_body.split("@")[1];
            editText_otp.setText(getOTP);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [`getOriginatingAddress()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage#getOriginatingAddress()) method

```
String originator = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
```

filter by this param, if `originator.contains(desiredPoneNumber)` then call `editText_otp.setText(...)`

also maybe `getDisplayOriginatingAddress()` methd may be helpful

Comment: Still don't work on the phone. It works on the emulator.

Comment: according to docs mentioned method returns `a String representation of the address; null if unavailable.`, so it looks like it is "unavailable" on your phone... sadly don't have idea why, probably Android version, provider or device/manufacturer may play a role in here, but this is just a suspicion.. anyway, good luck with that, powodzenia

Answer (score 0):

It works on the emulator but not on the phone.
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.probe;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class OTPReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static EditText editText_otp;
    public String str = "";

    public void setEditText_otp(EditText editText) {
        OTPReceiver.editText_otp = editText;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Deszczownie obj = new Deszczownie();
        String phone1a = obj.phonefromdzeszczownia1_phone_ET;
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            smsMessages = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                smsMessages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);

                String msg_from = smsMessages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                Log.v("msg_from >>", msg_from);

                if (msg_from.equals(phone1a)) {
                    str += smsMessages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    for (SmsMessage smsMessage : smsMessages) {
                        String getOTP = str.split("@")[1];
                        editText_otp.setText(getOTP);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```